# Image Compression using LZMA Python

Tags: python, compression, image-compression, lzma

Is there any way to compress Images through LZMA using Python. The pre-existing package can compress text files, but I cannot find any way to do so with Images. Any help is great!

Thank you!

Comment: Images are byte sequences like text files therefore it is theoretically possible but practically LZMA isn't that good for compressing images if they aren't very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`lzma` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html) provide following [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html#examples) of writing compressed file

```
import lzma
data = b"Insert Data Here"
with lzma.open("file.xz", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Observe that data is bytes (b-prefix) thus you might read any file in binary mode and use its' content as `data`, for example if you have say file named `image.png` you might do

```
import lzma
with open("image.png", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
with lzma.open("image.png.xz", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pre-existing package works with `bytes` type which can represent any binary data, not only the text. You just need to have your image in that format. In case if your image is already stored in the filesystem, this should work:

```
import lzma

with open('myimage.jpg', 'rb') as f:  # read bytes mode
    image_bytes = f.read()

compressor = lzma.LZMACompressor()
compressed_bytes = compressor.compress(image_bytes)
compressed_bytes += compressor.flush()

with open('myimage.jpg.lzma', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(compressed_bytes)
```

Answer (score -2):

Of course there is, first read the pictures with img = cv2.imread() using opencv, then the img value becomes a numpy list anyway, then convert this numpy list to a python list and you can save the lists in db or anywhere as text.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated and not efficient. If there is already an image file it can be compressed directly.

Comment: Why do you suggest using two 3rd party libraries just to read a file? Moreover, you will get a list of some values which are not clear that it's a binary data, you can't easily work with it. Then you convert it to text, so that creates a big overhead when storing it using some text coding and preserving the list structure to be able to deserialize it.

Comment: maybe it is difficult for you because you have no experience.

Comment: It is a very understandable library when you have experience with opencv, which I recommend to you.

Comment: But if one does not use opencv, why suggest using it just to read a file?
And saving an image as a list serialized to text makes a big overhead, it is not even about the difficulty for the developer, it is about performance and filesize.